# Java SWING program self-executing JAR - works only with java -jar

Tags: java, swing

I made simple Java Swing "program" which when select folder, It list image names with ';' something like img1.jpg;img2.jpg .... 
The program works in my Linux machine, but when I tried to use it in windows, the jar file is executed but it doesn't work (I don't receive the file names in the textbox). When I start the program with java -jar, it works.

Without java -jar (Direct running of the jar)
[image]

Running with java -jar 
[image]

For video - https://streamable.com/thpj7  ; Sorry for the music..

Comment: What's a "self executing jar"? If you mean a runnable jar, then yeah, that's how you run it. By including `-jar`, then the main class will be taken from the manifest file.

Comment: The "working" directory for the Jar is likely to be different

Comment: The jar is opening with double click on it.. the problem is that it doesn't execute the "textArea.setText( StringUtils.join(file.list(), ";") );" :) ... With java -jar it works...

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I recorded  a video - https://streamable.com/thpj7 
P.S Sorry for the music .... on the video.

Comment: *"I recorded a video.."* Where's the MCVE. Not watching a bloody video..